# eclipse Duplicate generator named "ID_GENERATOR" defined in this persistence unit

Tags: eclipse, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm currently having this issue which I don't have before I migrated to eclipse-jee-kepler. What I have:

I have 2 classes, base and the extending class:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "CUSTOMER_SEQ")
public class Customer extends BaseEntity {
}
```

Before I don't have this validation error but now eclipse is throwing it. I can compile, build and deploy successfully but the error marker is making it hard to pinpoint the compile errors when you really have one.

The error seems obvious, it's because I have ID_GENERATOR on all the extending classes. My question:
1.) Can I ignore this error?
2.) Any work around? Possibly using a different approach.

Comment: Is your `BaseEntity` an @Entity or a @MappedSuperClass?

Comment: It's a @MappedSuperClass.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured the problem, it was more of an eclipse JPA validation setting. To disable:

1. Select **Window » Preferences**
2. Expand **Java Persistence » JPA » Errors/Warnings**
3. Click **Queries and generators**
4. Set **Duplicate generator defined** to: `Ignore`
5. Click **OK** to apply changes and close the dialog

You can also set the value to `Warning` instead of `Ignore`.

Comment: Could it actually cause an error to occur, or two entities to use the same generator sequence unintentionally? I ask because hiding the warning/error doesn't make the condition go away :)

Answer (score 4):

The generator's name must to be unique by generator and it can be referenced by one or more classes.

The javadoc clearly says:

> (Required) A unique generator name that can be referenced by one or
>   more classes to be the generator for primary key values.

According to the java JPA 2.1 specification (SequenceGenerator Annotation of the JPA 2.1 - section 11.1.48):

> The scope of the generator name is global to the persistence unit
>   (across all generator types)

Answer (score 3):

For MyEclipse

1.Windows->Preferences

2.Myeclipse->Validation->JPA

3.Queries and generators

Generators is not defined in the persistence unit;