# No generator named "system-uuid" is defined in the persistence unit

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa

In eclipse Im getting the error "No generator named "system-uuid" is defined in the persistence unit"

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2") 
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
private String userId;
```

Previous posts have asked the same question and the answer has been to turn off this error in eclipse ? but this isnt possible in the version of eclipse I'm using (mars) and Id really like to know the cause of this.

Comment: What do you mean with _this isn't possible_? Can't you find the option or is it disabled or is the error still present after you checked it?

Comment: I had the same problem after upgrading to Mars This helped me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29118240/3977774