# Is it OK to have a duplicate generator named defined in the JPA persistence unit?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

My situation is described here:

[eclipse Duplicate generator named "ID_GENERATOR" defined in this persistence unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941191/eclipse-duplicate-generator-named-id-generator-defined-in-this-persistence-uni/29118240)

However my question is different and the selected answer does not solve it :

"*Is it valid to have multiple @SequenceGenerator **with the same name** even though it is used for this purpose [Hibernate : How override an attribute from mapped super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257921/hibernate-how-override-an-attribute-from-mapped-super-class) ?*"

If not valid, is there an alternative ?

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: I think it's valid, because in the end of the day, this is just how hibernate will map the entity to the sequence that will generate the ID when it persist it in the DB. Oracle for example does not care which tables use which sequence, since the sequence itself is an independent entity. IMO this warning (or error) makes more sense depending on the DBMS you're using. IMO, I'd just disable the error warning in eclipse.

Comment: Thanks Leo. Your comment could be a valid answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to section `11.1.48 SequenceGenerator Annotation` of the JPA 2.1 specification:

> The scope of the generator
>   name is global to the persistence unit (across all generator types).

So you can't have duplicate generators.

If you try to add the following two entities:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
public static class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pooled")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "pooled",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
        parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "sequence"),
            @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
            @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "5"),
        }
    )
    private Long id;
}

@Entity(name = "Announcement")
public static class Announcement {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pooled")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "pooled",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "sequence"),
                @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "10"),
            }
    )
    private Long id;
}
```

Hibernate will generate the following error message:

> Multiple references to database sequence [sequence] were encountered
>   attempting to set conflicting values for 'increment size'.  Found [10]
>   and [5]

That's because the identifier generator is global and those two sequence configurations will be conflicting.

Comment: thanks. So it not valid what alternatives can I use for my situation ?

Comment: The only solution is to avoid duplicated generators.

Comment: As described in my question, I have multiple sub-classes that inherit from an abstract class BaseEntity having the @Id defined there. What should I do if I want to generate unique Id sequence for each subclass ?

Comment: Just move the @Id from base class into each subclass.

Comment: Hi @VladMihalcea, If you change the value of the second generator's increment_size to 5, in which case both generators have the same parameters, then hibernate will show no error.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's valid, because in the end of the day, this is just how hibernate will map the entity to the sequence that will generate the ID when it persist it in the DB. Oracle for example does not care which tables use which sequence, since the sequence itself is an independent entity. IMO this warning (or error) makes more sense depending on the DBMS you're using. IMO, I'd just disable the error warning in eclipse.

Comment: This is no longer valid after Hibernate 5.13. Hibernate itself will throw an exception on application startup.